# Calculate the sum of the elements of an elementwise product of two matrices in Maxima

Tags: matrix, sum, product, maxima

What's in the title and I've tried thus far:

```
sum(lambda([i,j], M[i,j] * Ma[i,j]))
```

This expression gives me the `Wrong number of arguments` error. Doesn't `sum()` operate on lists, or am I missing something like an expression in the `sum` function call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the answer was rather simple:

```
lsum(i,i, list_matrix_entries(M3 * Ma))
```

This essentially translates to (\sum_{i\in{set of the elements of M*Ma}} i) in LaTeX.